# Programatically add linearlayouts on top of each other

Tags: android

I am trying to create multiple layers of linearlayouts one underneath the other but the result shows only the first linearlayout and I think that the other linearlayouts are to the right of each other rather than stacked on top of each other.  Can you help?

My code is as follows:

```
public void actionBrowse(){

    LinearLayout HolderLL = new LinearLayout(browseActivity);

    LinearLayout picLL1 = new LinearLayout(browseActivity);
    LinearLayout picLL2 = new LinearLayout(browseActivity);
    LinearLayout picLL3 = new LinearLayout(browseActivity);
    LinearLayout picLL4 = new LinearLayout(browseActivity);
    LinearLayout picLL5 = new LinearLayout(browseActivity);


    HolderLL.addView(picLL1);
    HolderLL.addView(picLL2);
    HolderLL.addView(picLL3);
    HolderLL.addView(picLL4);
    HolderLL.addView(picLL5);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for(int i=0; i<State.getInstance().getDesignUnit().getAllSavedImages().size(); i++){

        if(i<4) {
            ArrayList<DesignUnitViewer> savedImages = State.getInstance().getDesignUnit().getAllSavedImages();
            DesignUnitViewer dv = savedImages.get(i);
            Bitmap bmp = dv.getBacking_store();
            ImageView newImage = new ImageView(browseActivity);
            newImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            picLL1.addView(newImage, imageParams);
        }

        else if (i>= 4 && i <8){
            ArrayList<DesignUnitViewer> savedImages = State.getInstance().getDesignUnit().getAllSavedImages();
            DesignUnitViewer dv = savedImages.get(i);
            Bitmap bmp = dv.getBacking_store();
            ImageView newImage = new ImageView(browseActivity);
            newImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            picLL2.addView(newImage, imageParams);

        }
        else if( i >=8 && i<12){
            ArrayList<DesignUnitViewer> savedImages = State.getInstance().getDesignUnit().getAllSavedImages();
            DesignUnitViewer dv = savedImages.get(i);
            Bitmap bmp = dv.getBacking_store();
            ImageView newImage = new ImageView(browseActivity);
            newImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            picLL3.addView(newImage, imageParams);
        }else if (i >= 12 && i<16) {
            ArrayList<DesignUnitViewer> savedImages = State.getInstance().getDesignUnit().getAllSavedImages();
            DesignUnitViewer dv = savedImages.get(i);
            Bitmap bmp = dv.getBacking_store();
            ImageView newImage = new ImageView(browseActivity);
            newImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            picLL4.addView(newImage, imageParams);
        }else if (i >=16 && i<20){
            ArrayList<DesignUnitViewer> savedImages = State.getInstance().getDesignUnit().getAllSavedImages();
            DesignUnitViewer dv = savedImages.get(i);
            Bitmap bmp = dv.getBacking_store();
            ImageView newImage = new ImageView(browseActivity);
            newImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            picLL5.addView(newImage, imageParams);
        }

    }
    browseActivity.setContentView(HolderLL);
}
```

Comment: Try to set the orientation manually: `HolderLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`

Comment: If you set the backgrounds of the linearlayouts to a different color each then you can easily see which ones are where. Don't forget to set their orientation as well, I think they default to horizontal.

Comment: Thanks Vucko, it worked!

Comment: Thanks for your comment CookieMonster.